# How to prevent divs from overlapping with another div on resizing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My problem is when I resize the screen to make the screen smaller my divs begin to overlap after a certain point. However, the behavior that I would like to have is when there is not enough space for multiple divs in a row, then the divs must go under each other and fit the screen. I would like to maintain my grid gap when resizing or if possible use a flexbox instead.  This is my code:

```js
const gridTexts = [
  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's."
];

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
   <div className ="App">
    <div className = "grid-container" > 
      {gridTexts.map((gridText) => ( 
        <div className = "card">
          <span> {gridText} </span> 
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
   </div>,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.card {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: aqua;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` with `flex-wrap` to achieve what you want:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(33.3333% - 20px);
  padding: 30px;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: aqua;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="card">
    <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. </span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. </span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. </span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
  "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `display: flex` in the CSS of the wrapper/container

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        />
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
          
    
          .App {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            }
    
    .card{
        padding: 30px;
        height: 90%;
        background-color: aqua;
        min-width: 200px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30%;
        margin: 0 20px 30px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:767px) {
        .card{
            width: 100%;
            margin:0 5px 20px;
        }
    }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="card">
              <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
            "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
            "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
            "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
            "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
            "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
            "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <span> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
            "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset",
            "orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's. </span>
            </div>
          </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```